# In RBC model, why is importnt to match unconditional second moments?

Tags: macroeconomics, rbc

This is a sentence I just read in the literature:

*Following common practice in the RBC literature, we compare unconditional second moments in the model and in the data.*

I am wondering why. Why does it matter to match unconditional second moments in the model and in the data?

Comment: ? Well dont you want your model to actually fit data as opposed to be just theorizing?

Comment: @1muflon1 No, what I am asking is why matching unconditional second moments matters only in RBC model. What about NK mode? In New Keynesian model, literature don't compare unconditional second moments in a model to that in the data?

Comment: NK models do that as well, [here](https://d-nb.info/1026165547/34) is one example of PhD dissertation doing just that, and you can find many papers estimating NK DSGE models matching 2nd moments

Comment: @1muflon1, okay so matching unconditional 2nd moments is not unique only in the RBC model. Thanks!